# A smart solution for the appendix numbering

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

Ok i sum this up. I got some Exercises (6) and a couple of answers to each Exercise. All Exercises and Answers are included with graphicx. So i can autoref them in the discussion.
I want the Structure of the Appendix be of :
Named by Exercise 1 -- Answers to Exercise 1 -- Exercise 2 -- Answers .....
I want them to be named as E1 -- A E1 -- E2 -- A E2,
so when  \autoref{tim}  (look at the code) it shows up as: picture A E1: Tim

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Formalia der schriftlichen Arbeit
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}     
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    
\usepackage{parskip}
%\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

%Abstand nach Section

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{hi}
d
\newpage
\appendix
\section{Exercise 1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{E\arabic{section}}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth,angle = 270 ]{Eercises/E1.pdf}
    \caption{Exercise 1}
    \label{A1a}
\end{figure}
%this A E1 stands for Answer of Exc 1.
\section{A E1}\renewcommand{\thesection}{A E\arabic{section}}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{pictures/AE1/Tim.JPG}
    \caption{Tim}
    \label{tim}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Hello; since i am now to this Latex i am not sure which code to use; which means i havent tried something yet. I have seen some stuff with renewcommand; but in a different context. so i am not sure if it could work here

Comment: How are the exercise sheets done? Without seeing the code there's not much to say here. What is the sophisticated numbering in there? E1 -- Answers E1 --- etc. doesn't seem to be really complicated

Comment: Yeah, but how do i label my Appendix to E1 -- Answers E1 etc.? Which code does that?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{E\arabic{section}}`, assuming that you use sections in your appendix. Again -- without any code, it's guess - work

Comment: lets say i want  E1 -- Answers E1 etc., then     \section{Exc. 1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{E\arabic{section}} ..... \section{A -Exc 1}\renewcommand{\thesection}{A-Exc\arabic{section}} doenst work

Comment: @ziT: `doesn't work` is no useful description. Please provide the compilable code, as has been asked already

Comment: You've added the section number to your numbering for figures. Do you not want that? Your target numbering doesn't seem to include it e.g. 'E1' and not 'E1.1'. I thought I understood what you wanted, but playing with the code, I realise I don't.

Comment: Why should `\autoref{tim}` repeat the caption content as well, i.e. `Tim`?

Comment: It should repeat just the caption shortcut. if you can say that. Okay but lets clearify. In the Appendix there are two things which show up in the table of contant: f.e.  E1 - Exercise 1     page ....  . with autoref i want to show just the reference to  E1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trial of a solution, if I have understood the question correctly.

I've changed the `\thefigure` output slightly and added a macro `\autorefname` that combines `\autoref` and `\nameref`, which prints the caption title.

The starred version `\autonameref*` will not use a hyperlink, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Formalia der schriftlichen Arbeit
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{hyperref}     
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}

%\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

%Abstand nach Section

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\newcommand{\figureprefix}{E}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\autonameref}{sm}{%
  % Check for label existence first:
  \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    % Do nothing...
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      % No hyperlink, just the reference 'text'
      \csname \crtcrefcounter{#2}autorefname\endcsname\ \crtrefnumber{#2}: \crtrefname{#2}%
    }{%
      % Construct the hyperlink and link text as \...autorefname refnumber: caption (etc.) content
      \hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#2}}{\csname \crtcrefcounter{#2}autorefname\endcsname\ \crtrefnumber{#2}: \crtrefname{#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Foo section}

See \autonameref{Ente} or \autonameref*{A1a}

\autonameref{foo}
\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Exercise 1} \label{foo}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\figureprefix\arabic{section}}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \let\thefigure\thesection
  \centering
  \includegraphics{ente}
%  \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth,angle = 270 ]{Eercises/E1.pdf}
  \caption{Exercise 1}\label{A1a}
\end{figure}
% this A E1 stands for Answer of Exc 1.
\section{A E1}\renewcommand{\thesection}{A E\arabic{section}}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{ente}
  % \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{pictures/AE1/Tim.JPG}
  \caption{Ente}\label{Ente}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey that looks good! i only got the error  LaTeX Error: File `crossreftools.sty' not found.

Comment: @ziT: `crossreftools` is on CTAN, MikTeX and TexLive. (I know it exactly ;-))

Comment: Hey; my package manager of MikTex somehow fails to download. I downloaded it manually; i got now the crossreftoos.sty . but how to include it; since i still got the Error Message above

Comment: @ziT: Well, place it in your working directory then, where you stored the regular document ... I used MikTeX only once and found it not convincing, but I am Linux user anyway, so TeXLive is the way to go.